# How to access to a mapping output in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I have the next task in tf:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "managed_workers" {
  for_each = var.nodegroups[terraform.workspace]

  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
  node_group_name = each.value.Name
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.managed_workers.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.private.*.id
  tags = merge(
      var.tags[terraform.workspace], {
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"             = "true"
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${var.cluster_name}" = "owned"
      "type" = each.value.type
      "Name" = each.value.Name
      "ob"   = each.value.ob
      "platform" = each.value.platform
  })
```

The output of this task give something like that:

```
{
  "dev" = {
    "ami_type" = "AL2_x86_64"
    "arn" = "arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "capacity_type" = "ON_DEMAND"
    "cluster_name" = "EKS_Sps"
    "disk_size" = 20
    "force_update_version" = tobool(null)
    "id" = "EKS_Sps"
    "instance_types" = toset([
      "m5a.large",
    ])
    "labels" = tomap({
      "autoscalergroup" = "pool"
      "lifecycle" = "OnDemand"
    })
    "launch_template" = tolist([])
    "node_group_name" = "EKS-Node-Name
    "node_group_name_prefix" = ""
    "node_role_arn" = "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/EKS_Sps-node"
    "release_version" = "1.18.9-20210722"
    "tags" = tomap({
      "Name" = "EKS-nodegroup-name"
      "environment" = "dev"
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/EKS_Sps" = "owned"
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled" = "true"
      "ob" = "all" <<<<----- I NEED THIS VARIABLE
      "platform" = "api"
      "type" = "EKS-TF-Sps"
    })
}
```

Now I need to access from a new task like this, to the 'ob' value variable from other task using the output of this resource task. Would be something like: `each.value.tags(map).ob`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, its not clear. Is your variable a json string? What exactly is that, because it is invalid TF format.

Comment: This is the output of a specific resource task. I have removed some parts to show more clear. I get the output by terraform console so it is a JSON.

Comment: So the output you provided is `each.value`?

Comment: No, each.value is an example of what I need to get in the ouput I provided below.. Sorry if it is not clear at all :(

Comment: Its ok, but you have to ask question from the perspective of a viewer. From your question it is not clear what `each.value` is, how it relates to your output, where does the output come from, how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Let me update the OP. Thanks for your help @Marcin

Comment: Where would you use `each.value.tags(map).ob`? What is this "new task"?

Comment: The forum dont let me add more code in the OP... The new task is a aws_autoscaling_group_tag , there I have to get the value of the 'ob'. value = each.value.tags.ob , do you knw what I mean? @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, I think the following should be the way:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "example" {
  for_each = aws_eks_node_group.managed_workers

  #...
 
  tag {
    key   = "<some-key>"
    value = each.value.tags["ob"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Working!! You are the best dude!